# My own (new) class not found after xcode update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm developing iphone app. Yesterday I updated my xcode to to newest version and clean build folders (deleted it), then created new class (nothing special):

```
@interface EnemyFactory : NSObject {

}
+(Enemy *)properReferenceForName: (NSString *) name;
@end
```

Implementation is trivial and not important. What is happening now:
I've got sth like this:

```
Enemy *tempEnemy = [EnemyFactory properReferenceForName:@"enemyname"];
```

But code never reaches function properReferenceForName. I've got EXC_BAD_ACCESS with stack like this:

```
0   0x02a95e2b in realizeClass
1   0x02a96dad in _class_getNonMetaClass
2   0x02a90eb0 in _class_initialize
3   0x02a961f6 in prepareForMethodLookup
4   0x02a8f6c9 in lookUpMethod
5   0x02a8f836 in _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache
6   0x02a9dad3 in objc_msgSend
7   0x0000595d in -[GameLayer newEnemy:] at GameLayer.m:368
```

Before update. Xcode gives no warning or error. Symbols are declared.
What is interesting though is that: everything goes fine, when I debug step by step whole invocation...
I'm stuck with it for 8 hours.

**Update 1:**

`[[EnemyFactory alloc] init]` throws the same error

**Update 2:**

When I do this:
`[EnemyFactory alloc]` in some master class during initialization everything goes in flying colours.

Comment: What do ytou mean by "the newest version" of Xcode?  Do you mean 3.2.3?  Or 4?  If 4, you do realise it is preproduction software and all bets are off as to how well it works?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GameLayer.m line 368 something to do with [GameLayer newEnemy:]. I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: There is invocation of method which use line mentioned in post with EnemyFactory.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is never reaching your class method, the problem is where the stack trace starts, i.e. `[GameLayer newEnemy:]`

Look for objects that you may need to retain but are not retaining within the newEnemy method.

Comment: properReferenceForName is class method for EnemyFactory. How could I alloc it (class object?)? I'm relatively new to obj-c, mayby I'm missing something.

EnemyFactory creates only objects of given class by string name.

Referencing you mean #import it? Yes I do.

Comment: sorry, i lost my mind for a moment. you don't need to alloc a class object of course. updated answer.